# How to Understand the First Term in the Calabrese-Lefevre Distribution?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, entropy, analyticity, scaling

I am currently reading the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3059) and I am trying to understand the first term in equation (6) (reproduced below):

$$
P(\lambda) = \delta(\lambda_\text{max} - \lambda) + \frac{b \Theta(\lambda_\text{max} - \lambda)}{\lambda \sqrt{b\ln(\lambda_\text{max}/\lambda)}} I_1(2\sqrt{b\ln(\lambda_\text{max}/\lambda)})
$$

First we note that $f(z)$ is defined as

$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{b^k}{k!}\text{Li}_k(e^{-b}/z) = \frac{1}{\pi} \text{Li}_0(e^{-b}/z) + \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{b^k}{k!}\text{Li}_k(e^{-b}/z)
$$

Thus we see that

$$
f(\lambda - i\epsilon) = \frac{1}{\pi} \text{Li}_0\bigg(\frac{e^{-b}}{\lambda - i\epsilon}\bigg) + \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{b^k}{k!}\text{Li}_k\bigg(\frac{e^{-b}}{\lambda - i\epsilon}\bigg)
$$

The paper also mentions that $\lambda P(\lambda) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\mathbb{Im}[f(\lambda - i\epsilon)]$ and that the Dirac delta term of $P(\lambda)$ is due to the $\text{Li}_0$ term .

I was able to verify the Dirac delta when $\lambda = \lambda_\text{max}$, but I am having trouble verifying the Dirac delta when $\lambda < \lambda_\text{max}$. Basically, I have to show that

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \mathbb{Im}\bigg[\text{Li}_0\bigg(\frac{e^{-b} =  \lambda_\text{max}}{\lambda - i\epsilon} \bigg) \bigg] = 0$$

First I decided to calculate the imaginary part. I see that $\text{Li}_0(z) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty z^k $, where

$$z = \frac{\lambda_\text{max}}{\lambda - i\epsilon} = \frac{\lambda_\text{max}\lambda}{\lambda^2 + \epsilon^2} + i\frac{\epsilon \lambda_\text{max}}{\lambda^2 + \epsilon^2} \equiv \alpha + i\frac{\epsilon}{\lambda}\alpha$$

Since $\epsilon$ will approach $0$, we can let $\epsilon = f \lambda$, where $0 < f < 1$. Thus we see that $z = \alpha(1 + if)$

I began to calculate some of the terms in
$$
\mathbb{Im}\bigg[\text{Li}_0\bigg(\frac{e^{-b} =  \lambda_\text{max}}{\lambda - i\epsilon} \bigg) \bigg] = f\alpha + 2f\alpha^2 + (3f - f^3)\alpha^3 + (4f - 4f^3)\alpha^4 + (5f - 10f^3 + f^5)\alpha^5 + (6f - 20f^3 + 6f^5)\alpha^6 + (7f - 35f^3 + 21f^5 - f^7)\alpha^7 + ....
$$

I am positively sure that the first coefficient of each parenthetical term will equal the coefficient of $\alpha$. For small enough $\epsilon$, we see that $\alpha > 1$. and in the limit of smaller and smaller $f$, I see that the ratio of the $n+1$ term and the $n$-th term is $> \alpha > 1$. Thus by the ratio test, the imaginary part seems to diverge when $\lambda < \lambda_\text{max}$.

**But then how is the first term of $P(\lambda)$ the Dirac Delta function? Can anyone show me how to verify that the first term is $\delta (\lambda_\text{max} - \lambda)$ when $\lambda < \lambda_\text{max}$?**

Comment: Can't $\text{Li}_0(z)$ be written as a geometric series? From the definition you provided it seems that you can do the summation, and then find the imaginary part.

Comment: @Hosein The sum diverges because the magnitude of $z$ is greater than 1.

Comment: At the end, the imaginary part is finite or has a formal expression, otherwise the imaginary part is divergent. This is the case here, I did the naive geometric summation and got the delta function easliy.

Comment: @Hosein Here is what I am thinking. $\text{Li}(z) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty z^k$. I would have the find the imaginary part of this and then take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$.  This should give me $\delta(\lambda_\text{max} - \lambda)$, i.e. the final answer will be $\infty$ when $\lambda = \lambda_\text{max}$ and $0$ otherwise. When $\lambda \neq \lambda_\text{max}$, $|z|>1$ after a certain $\epsilon$ and $Li(z)$ diverges. So it seems to me that I cannot do the summation to find the imaginary part. That's why I focused on trying to find the imaginary part in the post.

Comment: and the imaginary part seems to diverge, but I am supposed to get 0. How do I show that the answer is 0? I only get the Dirac delta expression when $\lambda = \lambda_\text{max}$.